# Can I configure GNOME 3 to move a window to it's own workspace when maximized?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell

I'm using GNOME Shell 3.10 and would like to have each maximized window moved to its own workspace automatically.  Ideally I'd also like GNOME to prevent any workspace from having more than one maximized window in it.

So far I've looked through the tweak tool, as well as done some searching, but haven't found any leads.  Is this possible, either with or without a shell extension?

Answer (score 0):

There is a program which basically can do this.
You might want to look at

http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie

With devilspie you can customize what happens when windows are opened.
You could set them to be maximized and opened in a specific workspace.

There is even a GUI:

http://code.google.com/p/gdevilspie/

I used it differently tho, it might not be a 100% fit.

Comment: I just discovered that there is a new version of devilspie:  [devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/)